# Trying to use the Rails session flash, but getting nil.[] errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%# Flash-based notifications %>
<% if flash[:error].present? or flash[:notice].present? %>
  <div class="messages <%= flash[:error] ? 'error' : 'notice' %>">
    <ul id="feedback">
      <% if flash[:error].present? %>
        <li><%= flash[:error] %></li>
      <% end %>
      <% if flash[:notice].present? %>
        <li><%= flash[:notice] %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For some reason, as simple as it seems, my attempt to read from the flash inside a partial is producing this error, because the flash is set to `nil`.  Do I need to initialize it manually, or something?

This is Rails 3.1.0.  The error is on line 2 of the code snippet, where it tries to access `flash[:error]`.

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

I must be missing something.  I'm definitely not overriding it anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They key here is that you are trying to access the flash inside a partial.  You will need to do the following in your render method to pass the flash hash through to the partial:

```
render YOUR_PARTIAL, :flash => flash
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

**EDIT:**

Easier solution:  **rename your partial to anything but _flash.**

Because your partial was called flash, this happened:

> Every partial also has a local variable with the same name as the partial (minus the underscore). You can pass an object in to this local variable via the :object option:

The flash object was being overwritten by a local variable created with the name of the partial.

To clarify this a bit, let's say you have a comment model and you render the comments in the partial, you may do something like:

```
#_comment.html.erb
<h1>comment.user.name</h1>
<p>comment.body</p>
```

You would call this partial by doing something along the lines of:

```
render @customer
```

Now replace the word customer with flash and you will see why this was an issue.

This functionality that is **usually** convenience is what caused the issue.

Comment: I thought view helpers were accessible to my partials?  All my application helpers certainly are.  I'll give this a go, thanks.

Comment: Actually, after reading that link, your partial isn't called _flash is it?  If so, rename it to literally anything else and see if that works.

Comment: Well that certainly fixes it.  I guess I don't fully understand where `flash` comes from. Looking at the middleware it's a method on the Request.  I assumed it was exposed as a view helper since it's accessible to the view :)

Comment: Ah, let me try renaming the partial, you're right, my partial is called 'flash', but it's used in a string context: `render "shared/flash"`.

Comment: Renaming the partial helped. WTF. Thanks anyway, I can carry on (albeit scratching my head) now :)

Comment: I have added an explanation of this behavior.  Hope it clears things up.